# Distributing Values with a Cap

Tags: google-sheets, analytics, forecast

I am preparing an Operational Budget for next year for my company.

I am working with operations managers to define target at stock point level and I want to see how the monthly targets look using last year actuals distribution.

Bellow, you have a google docs link which you can use to better understand the situation.

I have trouble doing this with one of the KPIs which is %Orders Sent On Time. Since the company performs rather well, when I define a annual target of 99% and then distribute that by the months, using last year distribution, some of the months go over 100%. Do you have any methods which I can use to set a limit so that each individual month does not go over that.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z7WF-M5CaH52ANtYD9j-Z5_P0FvBiVZnmIQTonPaquU/edit?usp=sharing

**Edit:** I need the solution to be available on google sheets, for cooperation between teams.

Answer (score 0):

try in H22:

```
=IF($P$22*H10/$P$15>1; 1; $P$22*H10/$P$15)
```

Comment: That does not redistribute the values through the other months